# Flutter video player not updating when video link changes

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-test

I have used **chewie** as my flutter video player, and I have created some buttons where I have added some links, now when I click on the buttons, those videos are not loading or showing, only the initial video I have saved is being played. Can anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 0):

as you haven't added the picture with your question so it is difficult to point out the exact problem but I would suggest some method which might work for you. if you are using stateless convert it to statefull widget that might work and in the button on pressed method use setState method in that change the link I hope that will solve your problem.

Comment: 1. It is stateful already & 2. I used a button, the links get updated but the video player Don't update.

Comment: are you using setState method??

Comment: yes! But I do not how to implement setState for chewie, could you please help?

Comment: attach the picture of the code i would try to solve it if i failed to solve someone will solve it but without proper info about the problem its hard to point out the exact solution to the problem